# How can I resolve this error when linking to zlib under Linux in a D application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker, dependencies, d

I've mainly worked on Windows, so I'm quite unfamiliar with less common issues under Linux.

Here's the error I'm getting when dub tries to link my application:

```
/usr/bin/ld: .dub/obj/pixelperfectengine_pixelperfecteditor.o: undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: /usr/bin/gcc failed with status: 1
/usr/bin/ldc2 failed with exit code 1.
```

I've an image handling library as a dependency, which is required for the application, and it (obviously) uses zlib for *.png compression/decompression. I've installed zlib1g-dev for Ubuntu, but did not fix my issues, and the same exact code compiles without any issues under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link in `zlib`, as mentioned before.

I would recommend to do so via the "libs" array (see this page: https://dub.pm/package-format-json.html). The advantage of using `libs` over `lflags` is that `libs` will try to use `pkg-config`, which is a generic way to get linker / compile flags for C[++] libraries on POSIX. It works on Linux and Mac OSX. If `pkg-config` is not found, dub will just default to do what `lflags` would do in the first place.

Here's an example from my own project: https://github.com/Geod24/libsodiumd/blob/9b397645e2fc3ca502acb58e1b4631d3faf094e2/dub.json

Comment: Thanks, a `libs "z" platform="linux"` did the job in the dub.sdl file.

Answer (score 0):

> `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`

This error is telling you that you must add `-lz` to *command line*. I don't know what `dub` is, but somehow you must convince it to add `-lz` to the link command it constructs.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably enough to add `-lz` to the [lflags](https://dub.pm/package-format-json) in your dub file.